# Bloques pl pg sql

Tags: postgresql

Estoy empezando a usar plpgsql y postgresql y la verdad es que voy un poco perdido, tengo un ejercicio en que me piden que haga un bloque que incremente el sueldo de los empleados en un 10% del salario medio de los mismos, y he hecho esto:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment(salari INT) RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
    increment int NOT NULL := salari + ((avg(salari) * 10)/100);
BEGIN
    return salari + increment;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

El caso es que al aplicar la función no me devuelve un resultado correcto *(Sé que en vez del `return` he de hacer un `update` y tal, pero lo he puesto así para ir probando)*, imagino que será por que en vez de un int, he de trabajar con algún tipo de dato similar al double, pero no me lo reconoce.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de que podría hacer?

Comment: Excelente que hayas encontrado el problema por tu cuenta. Aun así, he votado para cerrar la pregunta como no relacionado debido a que se trata de un simple error tipográfico. Como explica [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *estas con frecuencia son resueltas de forma tal que es poco probable sean de ayuda a otros usuarios en el futuro.*

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de publicar esto y me acabo de dar cuenta de que en la variable `incremento` estaba sumando el salario; por lo tanto, estaba sumando dos veces el salario.

El código quedaría así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment(salari INT) RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
    increment int NOT NULL := ((avg(salari) * 10)/100);
BEGIN
    return salari + increment;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Y esto te funciona? Significa que esta es la respuesta a tu pregunta?

Comment: amenadiel, si tu respuesta soluciona tu pregunta, no te olvides de **[aceptar tu respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**; pero, si se trata de información adicional a tu pregunta, lo que debes hacer es [editar tu pregunta inicial](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/55536/edit). Gracias.

Comment: No me deja aceptar mi propia respuesta hasta dentro de dos días, por eso aún no la he marcado, y si, duda resuelta! Gracias :D